# Google Code Challenge -- Palindrome, parameters (int) not found

Tags: java

The goal of this program is to Given a number n, returns the smallest positive integer base b, at least 2 where the integer n is a palindrome.

Like:

Inputs:(int) n = 0,
Output:(int) 2

Inputs:(int) n = 42,
Output:(int) 4

but I keep getting the response:

> public static method answer with parameters (int) not found in com.google.challenges.Answer

I do have declared my method to take an `int` ...
Could somebody please help me understand what this error means and how I can fix it?

```
package com.google.challenges; 
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class Answer {   
 public static int Answer(int n) { 
    String y = "";
    String x = "";
    int k = 0;
    int b = 2;
    int ans = 0;
    if(n >= 0 && n <= 1000){
        for(b = 2; b < 1000; b++){

            k = n%b;
            x += k;
            while(n/b != 0){
                n = n/b;
                k = n%b;
                x += k; 
            }
            for(int i = x.length();i >= 0 ;i--){
                y += x.charAt(i);
            }

            if(x.equals(y)){
               ans = b;
               break;
            }

        }    

    }
    return ((int)ans);
 }
}
```

Comment: Your method has a capital A for Answer, your error indicates you are calling it with a lower case a.

Comment: Thank you! It works! but now, I fail at Test 2 to Test 4...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare "public static method **answer** with parameters (int)"
with your code "public static int **Answer** (int n)".

They don't start with the same letter, Java being *case-sensitive* and all.

Rename method to `answer`.

Comment: Thank you! It is all about that capital A...
It is my first time for asking question, thank you all for being so nice and patient.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a class is a great way to use object oriented code. In your code, you are using the class constructor to do the heavy lifting. Ideally the constructor only has initial information. For example:

```
public class Answer {
  public int input;
  public void Answer (int n) {
    input = n;
  }  
  public int output(){
    int ans; 
    //do the calculations here
    return ans;
  }
}
```

Then in your main file you can do something like this

```
public void main(){
  int somenumber = 42;
  Answer asker = new Asker(somenumber);
  asker.output();
}
```

Comment: Whilst this is generally a good suggestion, it doesn't specifically answer this question.

Comment: *"In your code, you are using the class constructor to do the heavy lifting"* There is no constructor at all in the code, so that is definitely wrong. Given the error message, the challenge solution should not have a `public static void main(String[])` method, but rather an `public static ??? answer(int)` method, so your answer here is not at all applicable to the question.